# How to correctly stop a Java applet after window closing

Tags: java

So, I made an applet game and put it on a webpage. I noticed that the sound kept playing after  I closed the page that the applet was in. I did some research and found out that the applet keeps running, even after the page closes. I read that you are supposed to use the `void destroy()` and `void stop()` methods to dump all resources. Is there a proper way to completely stop the app? Currently I just have it create a nullpointerexception to crash the app upon closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destroy methode is there for this use, i would just use it, you can make sure it gets called when the applet is finished, you can also call it in the finalize section like:

```
public void finalize () {
    destroy();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do already use the `destroy();` method. That's where I have the code to crash the applet.